# JavaScript map(), undefined property of object from the collection

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a collection of filter objects which is `this.selectedFilters`.

I use the JS map method to select only the `field` property of the filter object.

```
 console.log(this.selectedFilters.map((val) => {
            console.log(val);
            console.log(val.field);
            console.log(val['field']);
            return val.field;
        }));
```

The result is:

[image]

Can somebody tell me why does `val.field` gives an undefined value? :(

PS: I used TypeScript

**UPDATE:**

I think I know why `val` was a string. Maybe it's because `this.selectedFilters` is a ng-model of a `select` HTML element (multiple enabled) with options having an object value. Maybe the option value was converted from an object to a json string when transferred to the  `this.selectedFilters` model

Comment: what are the contents of `this.selectedFilters`

Comment: it's quite long actually. but it contains two of that object seen on the first log

Comment: What browser are you using? Just so we know how to interpret the console.log screenshot. *Looks* like Chrome, but...

Comment: What `JSON.parse(val)` gives?

Comment: yup, i am using chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely answer is that `val` is a **string** containing the JSON you see in the console. If it were an object, the console output would look different.

It looks like you need to put a `JSON.parse` in there. You haven't shown the original TypeScript, but in the JavaScript it would look like this:

```
console.log(this.selectedFilters.map((val) => {
    val = JSON.parse(val);    // <====
    console.log(val);
    console.log(val.field);
    console.log(val['field']);
    return val.field;
}));
```

Comment: tried to cast it via typescript:
   console.log((<holmes.reports.IReportFilter>val).field);
still undefined. or is my casting correct?

Comment: @RojBeraña: Would *casting* do a JSON parse? I tend to think not, but I don't "do" TypeScript. That would be an odd thing for a casting operation to do.

Comment: thanks! it worked!
 var r = JSON.parse(val);
(<holmes.reports.IReportFilter>f).field;

i will have to wait a couple of minutes before i can choose your answer :)

Comment: im confused on why typescript did not treat it as a holmes.reports.IReportFilter object when my typescript code is actually:
this.selectedFilters.map((val: holmes.reports.IReportFilter) => {
                console.log(val.field);
                return val.field;
            })

Comment: @RojBeraña: I think it's because `val` is a string, not an object. It would be strange behavior for a casting operation to guess that a string should be run through `JSON.parse` (as opposed to being interpreted as XML or any of several other data formats). But again, you'd have to talk to someone more familiar with TypeScript and its conventions. :-) Glad that helped.

Comment: i think i get it now. kinda remembered that typescript typing is only on compile time